# how to get a list of installed video players programmatically?

Tags: android, video, media-player

I know its similar to this question [How to get a list of installed media players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586684/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-media-players), but I am not able to get a list of installed players. Can someone help me on this?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,"1"); intent.setData(uri); 
playerList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

Comment: Pleas show us some code you have and how are you testing this?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,"1"); 
     intent.setData(uri);
     
playerList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

Comment: i get IllegalStateException at playerList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

Comment: are you positive there are applicatons and some videos present on the device?

Comment: yes. but I only want the list of players installed in the device

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent resolveIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
resolveIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"), MIMEType);
List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(resolveIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY| PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
```