# complete action using video player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

my app plays videos from URL when only default player is installed and when there are more than one it fails. I would like to show the dialog with the player installed like this picture http://mizuu.tv/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/default_video_player.jpg , I tried by following these posts to get the players installed [android-list of installed media players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972445/android-list-of-installed-media-players?rq=1) , [How to get a list of installed media players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586684/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-media-players) and [how to get a list of installed video players programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119379/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-video-players-programmatically) but it continues failing.

Thanks everybody in advance

This post has no answers [Before play video ask about the video player to play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944631/before-play-video-ask-about-the-video-player-to-play)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried by adding this code in Manifest to force to use MediaPlayer instead of to ask for video player because as the video is from internet the browser always apperars as player

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />  
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*3gp" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*3GP" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*mp4" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*MP4" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make your application able to respond to pick intents.

Specifically, you would declare an `intent-filter` with a concrete `action` that responds for audio/video intents (I don't know the names) in the AndroidManifest file.

Comment: thanks, could you see the code??