# android-list of installed media players

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I know that this post is like this question :
[How to get a list of installed media players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586684/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-media-players)
but i tried to test the code and it crashes !
this is the code :

```
public class Newactivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.display);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,"1"); 
intent.setData(uri);
List<ResolveInfo> playerList;
PackageManager packageManager = null;
playerList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    }
```

this is logcat errors:

```
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.upnpexample/com.upnpexample.Newactivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at com.upnpexample.Newactivity.onCreate(Newactivity.java:31)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-19 13:05:52.770: E/AndroidRuntime(558):  ... 11 more
```

any idea please ?

Comment: Have you added appropriate permission here?

Answer (score 1):

There may not be any content at that `Uri`, since you are making it up. Please use a `Uri` to an actual piece of content.

Beyond that, examine the stack trace in LogCat to see what you may be doing wrong.

---

**UPDATE**

```
PackageManager packageManager = null;
playerList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

Since `packageManager` is `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException` here. Use `getPackageManager()` to get an instance of `PackageManager`.

Comment: I examine the trace but i don't know what I must modify !

Comment: I do PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager(); but the NullPointerException persists

Comment: Make sure your MediaStore content exists. If it doesn't exist "packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);" will throw an exception.

Comment: @WilliamSeemann Thanks, In MediaStore is where I ask for video playerUri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,"1"); I tried the code in devices with only the defaulst player and others with two and the exception continues