# List installed media players

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I'm trying to get a list of all apps that can handle media installed on Android.

I've tried the methods listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4586684), but none of them worked. They all return an empty list and I have multiple media players installed, which are all recognized by Headset Droid (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tvk.headvol).

Can anybody suggest any alternative method or might have and idea what the problem can be? Do I need to set any permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
pkgAppsList = packageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
```

This provides a list with all apps that can handle the `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` intent. These are normally the media apps.