# how to get all music players

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mime-types

I want to query all activitys that can play a music file.
I have tried to get all music players like this:

```
Intent resolve_intent = new Intent();
resolve_intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
resolve_intent.setType("audio/*");
packages = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(resolve_intent, 0);

if (packages == null || packages.size() <= 0)
{
    //none found
}
```

but i everytime get an empty (or `null`) list...
if i do this for `type = "image/*` or `"video/*"`
i get all applications that can handle this type.

only for `"audio/*"` i get no players installed, even if i know that there is one...
so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586684/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-media-players

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fond it myself:

i forgot to set the Data, and i didn't know android uses the data too
to resolve the matching intents...

working code:

```
Intent resolve_intent = new Intent();
resolve_intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
resolve_intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/some/path/to/a/file")), "audio/*");
List<ResolveInfo> packages = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(resolve_intent, 0);
```