# How to organize apps into folders in Android Programming?

Tags: android, directory, launcher

I'm developing a launcher application. I want to auto organize apps into folders with subjects as Game, Social Network, Entertainment, Tool... But I do not know based on the information of the application to know what type it.

Sample : http://dantri4.vcmedia.vn/tI0YUx18mEaF5kMsGHJ/Image/2014/07/APUS-Launcher-3-feb4a.jpg

Comment: Is this question related to programming?

Comment: Yes, Android programming

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no straightforward way to achieve that.
The only thing that I could think about is to try to find some key words in the labels name of the apps.
Something like that:

```
private ArrayList<PackageInfo> searchPackageForString(PackageManager pm, String find){
    List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
    ArrayList<PackageInfo> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PackageInfo pi : packs) {
        if(pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString().toLowerCase().contains(find)){
            results.add(pi);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Then you could try something like That:

```
searchPackageForString(getPackageManager(), "game");
```

I didn't try it but I thing that this is the only possibly  direction.
Of course I can be wrong...

Edit:
Now that I looked in the pic you attached, I think that they check by find apps respond to Intents for action. 
here some example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28404480/3332634

Comment: i used intent for find apps. but classify applications into folders by topic, then there is no good solution

Comment: Of course there is no perfect solution because there is no API to what you asking. I think that my answer + the link I gave you is the closest you can get.

Comment: OK. thank you so muck. i will try to find a bettter solution then share it with you.